# Странная сортировка знаков за метки по прогрессу

Tags: дефект, знаки

[image: Скриншот]

На скриншоте видно 2 серебряные метки:

- [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) 348/400 баллов, 294/80 ответов
- [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) 350/400 баллов, 284/80 ответа

Очевидно, что 350/400 > 348/400, а требуемое количество ответов достигнуто в обеих, поэтому сравнивать его бесполезно. Так почему же метка с 348 баллами стоит раньше?

---

## Strange sort of tag badges by progress

There are 2 silver badges on the screenshot:

- [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) 348/400 score, 294/80 answers
- [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) 350/400 score, 284/80 answers

Definitely 350/400 > 348/400 and required number of answers is already achieved in both tags, so it doesn't affect progress. Why does tag with 348 score go before tag with 350 score?

Comment: а когда бронзовые знаки появляются в доступных? у меня ни одного нет, хотя уже есть двадцать ответов по одной метке.

Comment: Еще можно на javascript и jquery обратить внимание.

Comment: @4per, у меня всегда были.

Comment: @alexolut, там знаки разные - золотой и серебряный. У js больше 50%, у jq - меньше.

Comment: @Qwertiy смотрите на кол-во до достижения, а не на %

Comment: @alexolut, количество-то это да, но сортировка, вероятно, по проценту. Иначе пока ты не соберёшь 60% золотого знака, он будет после всех серебряных. Тут какой-то баланс нужен, чтоб он совсем не прятался. А вот среди знаков одного уровня неправильный порядок - это странно.

Comment: @Qwertiy оптимальнее было бы вообще по скорости приближения к цели сортировать

Comment: @alexolut, ага, но это им ресурсов не хватит в плане производительности)))

Comment: @Qwertiy да там всего-то поделить дельту очков на дельту времени:)

Comment: @alexolut, эм? Что за дельта времени? С момента регистрации? А если я тут 10 лет, неделю назад выучил новую технологию и за неделю собрал 50% метки, она где окажется? Не, тут надо брать изменение прогресса по дням, потом считать среднее за несколько дней. И ещё где-то прикрутить потенциальную зависимость от дней недели и учесть слияние меток... А ещё откаты серийных голосований, удаления вопросов и ответов, а может и пользователей. Так что тут жесть получается :)

Comment: @Qwertiy время от предыдущего изменения прогресса по метке. И наверное не очки, а % всё же. То есть скорость изменения относительной величины.

Comment: @alexolut, изменения происходят раз в сутки - перерасчёт прогресса по меткам и кэширование результата на сутки. Что дальше?

Comment: @Qwertiy сначала надо чтоб пофиксили текущий описанный дефект. А потом можно будет и новые алгоритмы во всей подробности обсудить :)

Answer (score 1):

На прогресс по знаку влияют два параметра — количество ответов и их суммарный рейтинг. Предполагаю, что количество ответов важнее. По крайней мере — для сортировки знаков.

У `css` рейтинг на 2 балла ниже, зато ответов на 10 больше.

Comment: Это объяснение по сути уже есть в самом вопросе. Смысл в том, что на сортировку это влиять не должно.

Comment: @alexolut Количество ответов - один из двух критериев. Статус выполнения критерия явно обозначен. Почему он не должен влиять на сортировку?

Comment: потому что необходимый для получения знака порог уже превышен. Сортировать имеет смысл по числу недостающих до необходимого пунктов. Для вариантов 284/80, 294/80 это число одинаково - 0.

Comment: @alexolut Согласен. Тогда, похоже, здесь не вопрос "почему" и не сообщение про дефект, а предложение по улучшению функционала.

Comment: скорее всего разработчики просто не учли этот момент или имеет место быть различное понимание правил сортировки. Здравый смысл говорит, что это баг. А вопрос "почему?" предполагает, что может быть есть какой-то скрытый смысл в этом.